# C++ calling a template method of a base clase in a derived class

Tags: c++, templates, cygwin, derived-class

I'm compiling in cygwin with gcc 4.8.2, and the compilation finishes without an error.  But when linked, I receive the following message:

> bin/libUsersMgmnt.a(CUsersMgmnt.cpp.o): In function
>   `nsUserMgmnt::CUsersMgmnt::CUsersMgmnt()':
>   /home/HCAST2/v1.05-dev/UsersMgmnt/CUsersMgmnt.cpp:23: undefined
>   reference to`int
>   nsMsgHandler::CMsgHandler::createLocationUserMap()'
>   /home/HCAST2/v1.05-dev/UsersMgmnt/CUsersMgmnt.cpp:23:(.text+0x19f):
>   relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol
>   `int
>   nsMsgHandler::CMsgHandler::createLocationUserMap()'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have this Base Class:

```
Header File CMsgHandler.h

namespace nsMsgHandler
{
    class CMsgHandler
    {
    protected:
        template<class enhFlags> createLocationUserMap();
    };
}
```

Code File CMsgHandler.cpp

```
... some code
using namespace nsMsgHandler;
... some code
template <class enhFlags>
int CMsgHandler::createLocationUserMap()
{
.....
}
```

This is the derived class:
    Header File CUsersMgmnt.h

```
namespace nsUserMgmnt
{
    class CUsersMgmnt : public CMsgHandler
    {
    public:
        CUsersMgmnt();
    };
}
```

Code file CUsersMgmnt.cpp

```
... some code
using namespace nsUserMgmnt;
... some code
CUsersMgmnt::CUsersMgmnt()
{
    this->createLocationUserMap<nsUserMgmnt::types::Class1>();
}
```

I'm pretty sure that there is an error in the code.  I tried to resolve this problem for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move your:

```
template <class enhFlags>
int CMsgHandler::createLocationUserMap()
{
.....
}
```

to CMsgHandler.h

otherwise compiler is not able to instantiate your template in  CUsersMgmnt.cpp